# Preview an image before upload with input type file of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search the internet and found this link http://jsfiddle.net/J3GP7/?
That link have one input type file and i want change to array of input type file link this

```
<input type="file" class = "focus_image" name="focus_image[]" >
```

How can i modify from one input type to array of input type?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the multiple keyword to the html element, like this:

```
<input type="file" class = "focus_image" name="focus_image[]" multiple="multiple" >
```

remind yourself about cross browser issues with this attribute!